# Custom iterator for linkedlist

Tags: java, for-loop, iterator

I've created a custom linkedlist. Also i've made an iterator for it. But program doesn't get in loop in the method size(), as i understand. What's wrong with it? Is it about my incorrect loop or `iterator()`. Every node has fields: `nextIndex`, `prevIndex`, `value`.

```
public class CustomLinkedList<E> implements List<E>{
    private ListNode<E> header = new ListNode<>();

    public CustomLinkedList() {
        this.header = new ListNode();
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        int size = 0;
        for(E it : this) {
            size++;
        }
        return size;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        if(this.header == null){
            return true;
        } else {return false;}
    }

    @Override
    public boolean contains(Object o) {
        if(((Integer) header.getValue() == 42) && ((Integer) header.getNextIndex().getValue() == 38)) return true;
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<E> iterator() {
        return new Iterator<E>() {
            private ListNode it = header;

            @Override
            public boolean hasNext() {
                return (it.getNextIndex() != header) && (it.getNextIndex() != null);
            }

            @Override
            public E next() {
                it = it.getNextIndex();
                return (E) it.getValue();
            }

            @Override
            public void remove()
            {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Iterator is read-only");
            }
        };
    }


    @Override
    public boolean add(E e) {
        ListNode<E> temp = new ListNode<>();
        temp.setValue(e);
        if (this.size() < 1) {
            header.setValue(e);
            header.setPrevIndex(header);
            header.setNextIndex(header);
        } else {
            temp.setNextIndex(header);
            ListNode tempLast = header.getPrevIndex();
            tempLast.setNextIndex(temp);
            header.setPrevIndex(temp);
            temp.setPrevIndex(tempLast);
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean remove(Object o) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean containsAll(Collection<?> c) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    @Override
    public void clear() {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    @Override
    public E get(int index) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    @Override
    public int indexOf(Object o) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends E> c) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You start with `header.getNextIndex() == null` Then call `add(E e)` once.
Inside `add()`, `size()` will return 0 so you set `header.setPrevIndex(header)` and `header.setNextIndex(header)`

Next you call `add(E e)` again`. Inside`add()`,`size()`will call`hasNext()`and`hasNext()`will check (it.getNextIndex() != header) && (it.getNextIndex() != null)` which will return **false** because `it.getNextIndex() == header`
therefore **`size()` will always be less than one**.

And there are plenty of other bugs in your code. A better partial implementation would be something like

```
public class CustomLinkedList<E> implements List<E> {

    private ListNode<E> header;

    public CustomLinkedList() {
        this.header = null;
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        int size = 0;
        for (E it : this)
            size++;
        return size;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return header == null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean contains(Object obj) {
        if (header != null)
            for (E it : this)
                if (it.equals(obj))
                    return true;
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<E> iterator() {
        return new Iterator<E>() {
            private ListNode<E> it = null;

            @Override
            public boolean hasNext() {
                if (it==null && header!=null)
                    return true;
                else if (it != null)
                    return it.getNextIndex() != null;
                else
                    return false;
            }

            @Override
            public E next() {
                if (it==null)
                    it = header;
                else
                  it = it.getNextIndex(); 
                return it.getValue();
            }

            @Override
            public void remove() {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Iterator is read-only");
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public boolean add(E e) {
        ListNode<E> temp = new ListNode<>();
        temp.setValue(e);
        if (header == null) {
            header = temp;
        } else {
            ListNode<E> it = header;
            while (it.getNextIndex() != null)
                it = it.getNextIndex();
            temp.setPrevIndex(it);
            it.setNextIndex(temp);
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: How to improve it to get header.value in first iteration of for? Now it doesn't. Because at the first iteration we get header.getNextIndex().getValue().

Comment: Yeah, you are right. I have edited the code in hasNext() and the it initialization, but not tested it. I think it´s OK now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `hasNext` and `next` methods of `iterator` to loop through the elements and increment the size, e.g.:

```
@Override
public int size() {
    int size = 0;
    for(Iterator<String> it = this.iterator(); it.hasNext(); it.next()){
        size++;
    }
    return size;
}
```

Comment: Still it doesn't get inside the loop. So the problem is either incorrect adding or hasNext(). Right?

Comment: If it does not get inside the loop then your list is likely to be empty.

Comment: It won´t get inside loop because `add()` method is wrong. Read my explanation why in another answer.